# How are OCR training datasets constructed?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, optical-character-recognition, r-cnn

For the sake of concreteness: let's suppose that the word "OCR" refers to any OCR system build on an R-CNN architecture. Similarly, in aims of simplicity, let's declare that we are interested in reading digits between 0 and 100.

**Question:** ***How should I construct a dataset (given the aforementioned goal and architecture) ?***

My understanding is that I need to collect images of all the digits from 1 to 100 and label them with its corresponding digit. Is this premise correct?

My struggle is that I can't fully understand how this seemingly tedious procedure is generalized to OCR that read more general types of characters (language-characters for example or if I generalize the problem to detect the numbers from 0 to $10^{10}$).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

OCR - *optical character recognition* identifies individual characters. So in the case of numbers, there are just 10 classes to learn. And this doesn't depend on how large numbers we are looking at. There is a separate step to segment observed numbers (or words) into single digits (or characters).

But on low-quality images this character segmentation is non-trivial, so better (and more complex) systems work with a larger context.